# How to disable colored emoji symbols on Firefox 32?

Tags: firefox, emoji

OS: Windows 8.1
Browser: Firefox
Version: 32

How do I disable colored emoji symbols?

✉,  - now is colored, I need to disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just needs add "Segoe UI Symbol" to font;

```
body{
    font:80%/130% "Segoe UI","Segoe UI Symbol","serif","sans-serif";
}
.icons{
    font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

Comment: as this did not work in my case here another solution for all who found this site via websearch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/9104335

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on my Windows machine by disabling the "Segoe UI Emoji" font in the system registry.  To use my fix, import this into regedit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
```

That replaces the colored emoji font with the black-and-white emoji font across the entire system, so in all browsers.

For the sake of completeness, if you later want the colored emojis back, just change "seguisym" to "seguiemj" in the above, and import it again.